# Approximation of Inverse Hessian or Inverse Hessian Square Root times a vector

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, hessian-matrix

I know there are good methods for approximating a Hessian times a vector without actually forming the hessian. [(Example here)](https://justindomke.wordpress.com/2009/01/17/hessian-vector-products/).

Are there any methods of approximating the Inverse of hessian times a vector? (e.g., $H^{-1}x$)?

What about $H^{-1/2}x$?